# Running a simple Python script in ps1

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to run a Python program from a ps1.

I have RunCommand.cmd -

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -f %*
```

And install.ps1 -

```
echo "installing"  > install.txt
python ./python/install.py
exit 0
```

With python/install.py -

```
open("pycreated.txt","a")
```

When the VM starts it runs the command

```
runCommands.cmd scripts\\install.ps1
```

But the python script doesn't work (or at least I can't see it)

The `install.txt` is created, but no `pycreated.txt`.

When I run it manually (CMD -> `runCommands.cmd scripts\\install.ps1`) it does work like expected.

What is wrong? it looks like the way the VM is running is different from how I run it.

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing. Are you running the install.py file or creating one? Confused about the file append line. Please post a fuller Python code block and not line snippets so we can understand context.

Comment: @Parfait thanks a lot for the comment. I'm in POC now so the code you see it's all the code. I fixed the naming to be clearer. it's only to see if the python runs from the ps1. the python itself is not the problem. My guessing that it's a matter of policy or something.

Comment: The script is creating `pycreated.txt`, not `install.py`

Comment: yeah, forgot to edit this as well. but the problem still exists.